# Diagnostics for Battery

Tags: hp, battery, diagnostic

I have no idea how to make HP run diagnostics without Windows, though I got these from HW probe. But don't know how to interpret results. I specifically am concerned about my battery, which dies without a warning, in almost 1/3 rd of the time promised and also doesnt charge above a certain point.

https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=f69580fced

[image]

Comment: Please add to the question the output of `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`

Comment: @dadexix86 done

Comment: It's the first time that I see this command fail, my knowledge ends here unfortunately, I hope that someone else will be able to help you :S

Comment: @dadexix86 thanks, but can you tell me of a better place to ask / bump the question to view?

Comment: @dadexix86 It's included to the probe. See https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=f69580fced&log=upower

Comment: can you link me somewhere @linuxbuild ?